# Url Rewriting like Subdomain in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite url as like subdomain style.

For example if main url is mysite.com/test than i want to rewrite it like test.mysite.com

**mysite.com/test => test.mysite.com**

Can you please suggest me what rewrite rule should i need to add in .htaccess file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437771/url-subdomain-rewrites-htaccess

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://$1.mysite.com [L,R=301]
```

Should do it, might need a little tweaking

Comment: Thanks for your reply @william. Let me check it.